# decreasing the jvm usage in elasticsearch when my python rest client is running

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have **10 nodes** in **one cluster (server)**. **Everynode** has **2 GB jvm** so they use **20GB** of the physical memory.

When I run my elasticsearch client after some hours, I get **jvm heap size error** or **circuit breaking exception**. After that, I check the elasticsearch its shutdown.

I have fetch datas from elasticsearch with [scroll api](https://kb.objectrocket.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-and-scroll-in-python-953) in **Python**.

I create indexes with below code.

```
es.index(index=name, id = id, op_type = 'create', doc_type= '_doc', body = body)
```

I want to ask that how decreasing the jvm usage in elasticsearch when my python rest client is running ?
Is there a way to add some codes after indexing or searching that decreasing the computing density ?

Thanks for answering

Comment: ten instance of elasticsearch in one server? that you called cluster?

Comment: run one node in on server and increase the heap size to 20G. and your problem will be solved. also you ask similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67568115/how-to-avoid-jvm-error-in-python-elasticsearch-rest-client

Comment: Yes, I have ten elasticsearch instance in one server. I have set jvm heap size 2 gb in elasticsearch yaml's in every node.

Comment: I have tried this before that, but what about yellow status if i run one node ? Where to store replicas ? What about the data that have in nodes, how can i recover them ?

Comment: Could you explain how it can solve this problem, because your answer is too costly

Comment: set replica to 0. the concept on replication is when you have more than one server.

Comment: when you dont have more than one server, you cant have HA and you dont need replication.

Comment: also change the indices template and set shard number to 1. you dont need more than that if your indices size is less than 100GB.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html

Comment: I will try this. But, every mapping I have 1 replica 1 primary. Logstash instances running, other clients running. So I have too many datas, How can I recover data ? This is really important issue

Comment: for recovering and having HA you need more than one server. in that situation, you can set replica more than 0. your question is like you are putting ten kid on one adult bicycle and asking how I can protect them from falling?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/indices-shrink-index.html

Comment: Shrink API moves data from an index to another index. But, In this scenario I will delete 9 of my nodes. So I will need to move this data to new node.  I need something like in sql dump.  How to recover ?